# C# onclick call method of parent page from within a control template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an .ascx page that is loading a control template via a placeholder.

```
<div id="TemplatePages" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="repeater" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

I am adding a control template (the same template twice)

```
some ctrl = (some)Page.LoadControl(_somePath);
ctrl.Item1 = "Value";
ctrl.Item2 = something.Value;
ctrl.Item3 = someOtherThing.Value;
repeater.Controls.Add(ctrl);

some ctrl2 = (some)Page.LoadControl(_somePath2);
ctrl2.Item1 = "Value";
ctrl2.Item2 = something.Value;
ctrl2.Item3 = someOtherThing.Value;
repeater.Controls.Add(ctrl2);
```

The template contains some simple forms.  However, onclick of any button/link within the template, I want to save the values of BOTH instances of the control template.  On the page that loads the form, I have my save button that saves the values of both forms, but that is on the main page method. I want to save the values of all the fields from both forms from within the template itself.

I cannot fire the "onclick" of the main save button because that will cause a postback to happen and I need to fire other methods from within the template after the forms are actually saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my user control save method (which was initially just saving the single instance of the control was modified to look like the following)

```
public void saveData()
    {
        var phBOM = (PlaceHolder)this.Parent.FindControl("phBOM");
        foreach (UserControl ctrl in phBOM.Controls)
        {
            var type = (ucBOM)ctrl;
            var item = ConstructFormData(type);
        }
    }
```

and then inside my ConstructFormData, I simply had to add "this." before each field.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the onclick event of main form, but in the onclick event you will need to call the methods of the user control you are using.

If the public method exposed in your user control is called `SaveFormValues( )`,  then you should use code like below in your main page. I am assuming there is a placeholder with id of `plh1` in your main page to which you will add your user control instances and also the name of your user control is `WebUserControl`.

Note how the user control is being accessed by passing the id of  user control to `Page.FindControl` method. Once you find the user control, then simply call the publicly exposed method of `SaveFormValues`.

**Main page code-behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     WebUserControl webControl21 = (WebUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl.ascx");
    webControl1.ID = "template1";
    WebUserControl webControl22 = (WebUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl.ascx");
    webControl2.ID = "template2";
    plh1.Controls.Add(webControl1);
    plh1.Controls.Add(webControl2);
}

protected void btnMainFormSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((WebUserControl2)Page.FindControl("template1")).SaveFormValues();
    ((WebUserControl2)Page.FindControl("template2")).SaveFormValues();
}
```

**Main page markup**

```
     <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plh1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:Button ID="btnMainFormSave"  runat="server" Text="Save Form Values"
            OnClick="btnMainFormSave_Click"/>
```

**Publicly exposed method in your user control**

```
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void SaveFormValues()
    {
        //TO DO? Save your user control values
        //lblMessage.Text = "form values have been saved for this template";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I may not have been clear in what I need.  What you posted is exactly what I have.  What I need is if in the template/WebUserControl, I have a button that is clicked.  I want that button to save the values from ALL INSTANCES of that WebUserControl.  Using your example. I want that button to fire the Main page btnMainFormSave_Click method.  The reason being is that simply calling the SaveFormValues method will only save the fields within that instance of the control, when I need to to save for all.

Comment: So, you want to call the main page save button click event, when any one of the user control save button is clicked?  I am assuming you already have code in main page save button click event to save values for all user controls.

Comment: Yes, I used that code and modified it in the User Control Template to get my solution.